# Javascript no me crea el div

Tags: javascript

Quiero que el texto ingresado en el input quede dentro de un div creado y se vaya al div 'caja', pero no me quiere funcionar ¿qué hago?

```js
<script>
function crear() {
var texto = document.getElementById("text").value;
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.appendChild(texto);
document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(node);
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text"/>

<button onclick="crear()">Crear caja</button>

<div id="caja"></div>
```

Comment: Deberías empezar usar ya propiedades modernas como document.querySelector('#caja')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define el id "text" a tu `input` para que puedas obtener sin problema su valor :

y usa `node.innerHTML = texto`; para asignar el valor al `div`.

---

```js
    function crear() {
    var texto = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.innerHTML = texto;
    document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(node);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="text"/>

    <button onclick="crear()">Crear caja</button>

    <div id="caja"></div>
```

---

Si deseas agregar otro elemento por ejemplo un h1 cuando generes el div, usa appenChild() para esto, ejemplo:

```js
       function crear() {
        var texto = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var node = document.createElement("div");
        node.innerHTML = texto;
        document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(node);
        
        //Agrega otro elemento al div
        var header = document.createElement("h1");
        header.innerHTML = "Header90";
        document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(header);

       }
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="text"/>

        <button onclick="crear()">Crear caja</button>

        <div id="caja"></div>
```

Comment: Y si quiero agregar otro elemento h1 por ejemplo. como hago para que ese h1 quede dentro del div creado?

Comment: @Header90 simplemente agregalo dentro del div: <div id="caja"><h1>Header90</h1></div>

Comment: No me entendiste. quiero crear otro elemento pero esta vez un h1, quiero que ese h1 quede dentro del otro elemento creado, es decir el div.

Comment: ya, simplemente agregalo mediante:
        document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(header); , agrego esto en la respuesta.

Comment: ya lo hice, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

veo 2 problemas.

```
<script>
function crear() {
    var texto = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var node = document.createElement("div");

    //Aca, se agrega al objeto/variable node, el texto, en la propiedad innerText
    node.innerText = texto;

    //Y este no va
    //node.appendChild(texto);
    document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(node);
}
</script>

<!-- Acá, en el input, se debe referenciar el id=text u otro nombre -->
<!-- luego, en el codigo javascript, efectivamente se puede usar getElementById -->
<input type="text" id="text" name="text"/>

<button onclick="crear()">Crear caja</button>

<div id="caja"></div>
```

Comment: Y si quiero meter etiquetas dentro de ese div generado? no serviria nodeapped...

Comment: por su puesto que puedes, pero appendchild es para agregar un objeto, no es para un texto.

Answer (score 1):

EL error es que tu input no  tiene un id:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function crear() {
    var texto = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.innerHTML= texto;
    document.getElementById("caja").appendChild(node);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="myText"/>

<button onclick="crear()">Crear caja</button>

<div id="caja"></div>
</html>
```